# Recyclerview items are automatically getting clicked on scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When i scroll recyclerview. items in it are automatically getting clicked. how to fix this problem.

this is my recyclerview (OnItemTouchListner).on scrolling items automatically
get clicked

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
                    View view=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(),e.getY());
                    String profile=null;
                    if(view!=null){
                        int position=rv.getChildAdapterPosition(view);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(arrayList.get(position));
                            profile=jsonObject.getString("profile");
                        } catch (JSONException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                        bundle.putInt("position",position+1);
                        bundle.putString("profile",profile);
                        intent.putExtras(bundle);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: You need to provide more details and the relevant code. This is neither helpful to anyone nor can anyone answer your questions

Comment: add code and description to question.

Comment: Provide your click listener method code

Comment: i update my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
holder.yourLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(arrayList.get(position));
                        profile=jsonObject.getString("profile");
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),ProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                    bundle.putInt("position",position+1);
                    bundle.putString("profile",profile);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: why items were getting clicked on scrolling in my previous code

Comment: because when you scroll, you touch the cell of the recyclerview. you used recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener. you scroll, you touch, so it works. user recyclerview.setOnClickListener instead. recommened to use click listener within the adapter class.